# swift3 admob working only in simulator. Not working in real iPhone

Tags: iphone, swift3, admob, simulator

I try to put admob into my swift3 project, it is working well in a simulator, but the fullscreen adv is not working in real iPhone device. Please kindly help to solve this issue.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class AutoGADViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

var fullScreenads : GADInterstitial!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

self.fullScreenads = CreatAndLoadInterstitial()

}



func  CreatAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
    fullScreenads = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-2552245081934602/3265493331")

    guard (fullScreenads) != nil else {
        return fullScreenads
    }

    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    fullScreenads.load(request)
    fullScreenads.delegate = self

    return fullScreenads

   }
}
```

Comment: **request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]** remove this line and try

Comment: it works and thank you

Comment: I try to add self.fullScreenads = CreatAndLoadInterstitial() in viewdidappear(), but it keep popup adv. Is any way to popup adv before app loading?

Comment: sorry i am not clear